# Stack Exchange sites FAQ still lists 30 vote limit - needs updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, faq-update-request, voting-limits

Stack exchange FAQ sites list this:

> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per
>   user per day, and you can earn a
>   maximum of 200 reputation per day
>   (although accepted answers and bounty
>   awards are immune to this limit).
>   Please note that votes for posts
>   marked “community wiki” do not
>   generate reputation.

This needs to be updated to the new 40 vote limit.  A question was posted in money's meta because of the text of the Vox Populi badge and the reference to 40 votes.  I hoped to point them to the FAQ, but the FAQ is wrong.

Comment: This limit is per site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now completed -- sorry for the delay.